# My transition for a <div>'s height is not taking place in my pen on codepen.io

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So, I've got my own pen on codepen.io using a transition to change the height, and I don't know what's happening. CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME Please? I've got a single clue why but for some reason 1 of them is working?? I'm SUPER confused, this is not like a normal web-developing time to me.. sort of I've tried my best to think of why it might work myself but I've managed to get 0 luck D-:

So I tried this code:
HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>A Title</h3>
    <p>A Description for the story</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("/images/MyImage.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: calc(66vw - 4rem);
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem 5rem black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.card:hover .text {
  height: 3rem;
}

.text h3 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  color: white;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  cursor: default;
}

.card:hover h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50vh;
}

.text p {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.card:hover .text p {
  display: block;
}

h3::selection, p::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
```

can anybody tell me why the paragraph and the text just won't come up with a transition, I gave you everything in case anything isn't supposed to be like that. and by the way the image is a tropical beach with a non-used name by me, I just wanted you to know that there's ACTUALLY an image there just incase it has anything to do with it's children's transitions.

Comment: Are you sure the transition is not working? I just tried both on codepen.io and locally and it works perfectly.

Comment: !! Yes, I am sure it doesn't work, I copied it right from the clipboard.. OK here's the REAL code I used. click this link:  [The Pen](https://codepen.io/dolfandds/pen/jOpJYEQ) and I know it has a rubbish story.. but It's the transition I'm worrying about, I think it'll be good if it works and also look at the black bit at the bottom, it's not got it's transition, that's what it should have with a transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make *transitions* you need a **starting point** and an **ending point**. However, **not** all properties "create" a smooth transition, for example from `display: none;` to `display: block;` no transition will be created (same from `visibility: hidden` to `visible`).

For this reason, if you want to create *smooth transitions* you have to use properties that allow you to do this. In this case for the `p` you have to use the `opacity`, while for the `div` you **can't** make a smooth transition **from** `auto` **to** `3rem`, so you will be forced to set a `height` other than *auto*.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("/images/MyImage.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: calc(66vw - 4rem);
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem 5rem black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: .5rem;
  width: inherit;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.card:hover .text {
  height: 3rem;
}

.text h3 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  color: white;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  cursor: default;
}

.card:hover h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50vh;
}

.text p {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.card:hover .text p {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

h3::selection, p::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>A Title</h3>
    <p>A Description for the story</p>
  </div>
</div>
```